# Putting an image in above

Tags: html, css

I'm currently making a project which consists of a website that streams movies and tv shows, in the tv show section I want to insert a image to illustrate each episode. My idea is making a second image that shows which episode that image corresponds to and I'm having a little trouble putting the second image above the first one.

```css
.episode-slidebackground {
    width: 950px;
    height: 220px;
    background: rgba(162, 162, 162, 0.24);
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.episode-slidebackground img {
    width:182px;
    height:136px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}


.episode-slideimgbackground{
width: 925px;
margin-left:10px;
margin-right:10px;
height:145px;
background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.24)
}

h1{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #f2a223;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;

}
h2 {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #f2a223;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #f3b12b;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h5 {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;

}

h6 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="episode-slidebackground">
                <h6>Temporada:1 2 3 4 5 6</h6> <br>
                <h2>Episódios:</h2>
                <div class="episode-slideimgbackground">
                <img src="img/1.jpg">
                <img src="img/2.jpg">
                <img src="img/3.jpg">
</div>
                </div>
```

This is the page without the second image:
[image: this is the page without the second image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try and work with CSS's `position` attribute. This will enable you to have more control over your elements.

The two position attribute's you need to make use of are `absolute` and `relative`.

Basically, if you have a `div` that is set to `position: relative` that means that you can adjust that `div`'s position without changing the layout of your webpage. It also means that any children elements of that `div` with the `position: absolute` can be positioned anywhere inside of that `relative` `div`.

```css
.videoContainer {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.videoImage, .videoCaption {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
}

.videoCaption {
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50px;
  background: Gray;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoContainer">
  <img class="videoImage" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/>
  <div class="videoCaption">Some Caption</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `z-index` this is an css attribute that determines which element is on top

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index